# How to set the number of NameNodes, DataNodes, Mappers and Reducers in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reducers, namenode, mappers

I want to know how to set the number of

*NameNodes*

*DataNodes*

*Mappers*

*Reducers*

in code/configuration of *Hadoop*.

Answer (score 1):

**Namenode and DataNode count** is decided by your business requirements. You don't set them by programming.

If you need scalability, you have to look into concepts of HDFS federation.

Refer to this documentation [page](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html) for more details about Federation.

> In order to scale the name service horizontally, federation uses multiple independent Namenodes/namespaces. The Namenodes are federated; the Namenodes are independent and do not require coordination with each other. The Datanodes are used as common storage for blocks by all the Namenodes.

[image]

**Number of mappers** is decided by input splits.

You can set the **number of reducers** programatically but framwork is not obligated to obey your recommendation.

So it's better to keep the decision to Hadoop to take decision on number of Mappers and Reducers.

Have a look at this related SE question:

[How hadoop decides how many nodes will do map and reduce tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282121/how-hadoop-decides-how-many-nodes-will-do-map-and-reduce-tasks/33287988#33287988)

**EDIT:**

Hadoop cluster size : 
1. Identify data requriements from your business needs
2. Identify replicaiton factor for your data
3. Calculate data exlposion rate in coming years
4. Once you have above data, you can think on ideal cluster size and hardware requirements for Namenode and Datanode.

Refer to this cloudera [article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-select-the-right-hardware-for-your-new-hadoop-cluster/) for more details.

> The right level of parallelism for maps seems to be around 10-100 maps per-node" node here means NameNode or DataNode?

it's Datanode.

> when talking about Mappers some says same number as splits, another says same number of blocks, while others say it is determined by the framework

it was decided by hadoop framework depending on number of input splits.

Have a look at related SE question:

[How does Hadoop perform input splits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831507/how-does-hadoop-perform-input-splits/34247868#34247868)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I understand that NameNodes can be set via configration, mappers&reducers are determined by Hadoop framework. Now what about the DataNodes how to set their number?
Also in the second link you gave it to me it is mentioned:
"The right level of parallelism for maps seems to be around 10-100 maps per-node" node here means NameNode or DataNode?
And when talking about Mappers some says same number as splits, another says same number of blocks, while others say it is determined by the framework and may not give exact number of splits or blocks, so which is right from above?